# Alphabetizing code leaves a superfluous `""` in my sorted array

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

Why does the following code leave an extra `""` in my final array?

```
puts 'Type in as many words as you\'d like. When you\'re finished, press enter on an empty line'
array = []
input = ' '
while input != ''
  input = gets.chomp
  array.push input
end
array.sort
```

Comment: Because `array.push input` is called for every input, even the final empty line.

Comment: Simple debugging steps using Pry or byebug would have quickly showed the problem. I'd recommend learning about debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You push `input` onto the array regardless of whether there was any or not.  Since you want to check the terminating condition between reading and pushing, this is a good place to use a `break`:

```
puts 'Type in as many words as you\'d like. When you\'re finished, press enter on an empty line'
array = []
loop do
  input = gets.chomp
  break if input.empty?
  array.push input
end
puts
puts array.sort
```

Answer (score 0):

As Stefan mentioned in the comment it is because you're always pushing what you get.

You should swap the two methods inside the loop so that it checks the condition between the gets and the push.

```
puts 'Type in as many words as you\'d like. When you\'re finished, press enter on an empty line'
array = []
input = gets.chomp
until input.empty?
  array.push input
  input = gets.chomp
end
```